# How to allow only US phone numbers with regex validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, validation

I have three different input fields for the phone numbers. Each field should only allow US phone number format. Here is example:

```
(564) 332-9088 //allowed format.
```

User should be able to enter phone number only in the format I have above in example. So first three digits should be in the braces `()` then space (can be ignored) followed with 3 digits and then `-` dash and last four digits. I have created pattern regex but that won't require `()`. User can enter phone number in this format as well `336-678-8999` that should not be allowed.

```html
<form name="testFrm" id="testFrm" method="POST" action="#">
  <label for="wphone">Work Phone:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phoneW" id="phoneW" pattern="(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}" maxlength="14" title="US based Phone Number in the format of: (123) 456-7890" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" required />
  <span><input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" value="Submit" /></span>
</form>
```

If anyone knows how I can adjust my code to accept only `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` please let me know or if you have better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work for you to allow **only** `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` format. Here **space** is optional after the `(xxx)`

```
\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}[-]?\d{4}
```

Explanation

`\(` -> matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)

`\d` ->  matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{3}` -> Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times

`\)`->  matches the character ) literally (case sensitive)

`[ ]?`-> Matches space between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\d` -> matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{3}`-> Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times

`[-]?`-> Matches dash between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\d`-> matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{4}`-> Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times

See demo : https://regex101.com/r/Ws3c1t/1